# vulkan build undefined reference to `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties@12'

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, vulkan

so i was trying to set up vulkan on vscode in windows.

and i strugle to fix the link errors.
at first i had problems with GLFM

but it looks like i sorted it out, by compiling it with mingw myself.

but now i guess the following link error

```
undefined reference to `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties@12'
```

how should i resolve that issue?

my makefile looks like that at the moment:

```
DIR1 := external/GLFM/include
DIR2 := external/glm/
DIR3 := external/vulkan/Include
INC=$(DIR1) $(DIR2) $(DIR3)
INC_PARAMS=$(foreach d, $(INC), -I$d)

LDPATHS2 := -Lexternal/GLFM/Lib/ -Lexternal/vulkan/Lib/
LDLIBS = -lglfw3 -lvulkan-1 -lgdi32

VulkanTest: main.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PARAMS) $(LDPATHS2) -o  VulkanTest main.cpp $(LDLIBS)
```

EDIT:
i have added the -lgdi32 as that seemed to get rid of all of those
link errors:

```
C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRgsVDp.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7c): undefined reference to `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties@12'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1d4): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x257): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xa49): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xa64): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xf06): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xf23): undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xf33): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x107b): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1098): undefined reference to `_imp__SetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x10a8): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1f5): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDIBSection@24'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateBitmap@20'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x295): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteObject@4'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x387): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteObject@4'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x397): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteObject@4'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0xbe1): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateRectRgn@16'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0xc41): undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteObject@4'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x6c4): undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0xbbf): undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0xf4a): undefined reference to `_imp__SwapBuffers@4'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x126e): undefined reference to `_imp__ChoosePixelFormat@8'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x128b): undefined reference to `_imp__SetPixelFormat@12'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x15b4): undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
external/GLFM/Lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x15fd): undefined reference to `_imp__SetPixelFormat@12'
```

Comment: it's Windows environment judging by gdi32 reference?  are you trying to actually build 32bit app?  mediating library vulkan-1 is in other folder, Lib32.

Comment: actually iam trying to build x64
but without the gdi32 i get a lot of other issues

Comment: then  check  if adding -m64 to CFLAGS solves issue.